# Asymptotic of Fourier coefficient and generalised hypergeometric function

Tags: asymptotics, fourier-series, hypergeometric-function

I would like to study the asymptotic behaviour of the integral
$$
I_n= \int_0^1 t^{-\alpha} \cos (n \pi t)\, dt, 
$$
where  $\alpha\in (0,1/2)$ is a fixed constant. In particular, I am interested in the decay order of $I_n$ (preferably depending on $\alpha$) as $n\to \infty$.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+t%5E%28-a%29+cos%28n*pi*t%29+on+%5B0%2C1%5D) suggests that
$$
\int_0^1 t^{-\alpha} \cos (n \pi t)\, dt = \frac{_1 F_2(\frac{1-\alpha}{2}; \frac{1}{2},\frac{3-\alpha}{2}; -\frac{1}{4}n^2\pi^2)}{1-\alpha}.
$$
I am not sure how to prove this formula. Moreover, as I am not familiar with the generalized hypergeometric function, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Is there a reference on the asymptotic behavior of $_1 F_2$ or more directly the quantity $(I_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Express $\cos$ as a series and integrate term by term.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Are you commenting on the approach to prove the identity? I will try it now. Do you have any hint to proceed from there and study the behaviour of $(I_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Oh, yes that's for deriving the identity. There are asymptotics for hypergeometric functions you can find. The NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions has some. They have the text digitized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more convenient to consider $\displaystyle I(n,\alpha)=\int_0^1t^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi nt}dt$; then our integral is the areal part of $I(n,\alpha)$. Making the substitution $x=\frac{t}{n}$
$$I(n,\alpha)=\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\int_0^nx^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi x}dx=\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi x}dx-\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi x}dx=I_1+I_2$$
The first integral is well-known and can be evaluated, for example, by means of integration in the complex plane.
Let's consider the integral along the following contour:
[image]

$$\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\oint z^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi z}dz=\int_r^R z^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi z}dz+I_R+\int_R^r \big(e^\frac{\pi i}{2}z\big)^{-\alpha}e^{-\pi z}idz+I_r\tag{0}$$
There are no singularities inside the contour; therefore, $\displaystyle \oint=0$.
It is not difficult to show that the integrals along the big and small quarter-circles $\,\displaystyle I_r, I_R\to 0\,\,\text{at}\, r\to 0\,\, \text{and}\,\, R\to\infty\,$ correspondingly.

Therefore,
$$I_1=\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi x}dx=\frac{ie^{-\frac{i\pi\alpha}{2}}}{n^{1-\alpha}}\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{-\pi x}dx=\frac{e^\frac{i\pi(1-\alpha)}{2}}{n^{1-\alpha}}\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{-\pi x}dx$$
$$I_1=\frac{e^\frac{i\pi(1-\alpha)}{2}}{(\pi n)^{1-\alpha}}\Gamma(1-\alpha)\tag{1}$$
$\displaystyle I_2$ we evaluate via integration by part
$$I_2=-\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi x}dx=-\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\frac{e^{i\pi z}x^{-\alpha}}{i\pi}\bigg|_{x=n}^\infty-\frac{\alpha}{n^{1-\alpha}i\pi}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha-1}e^{i\pi x}dx$$
$$=i\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\alpha}{(\pi n)^2}+\frac{\alpha (1+\alpha)}{\pi^2 n^{1-\alpha}}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha-2}e^{i\pi x}dx\tag{2}$$
Taking together (1) and (2)
$$I=\frac{e^\frac{i\pi(1-\alpha)}{2}}{(\pi n)^{1-\alpha}}\Gamma(1-\alpha)+i\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\alpha}{(\pi n)^2}+\frac{\alpha (1+\alpha)}{\pi^2 n^{1-\alpha}}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha-2}e^{i\pi x}dx$$
Taking the real part
$$\int_0^1 t^{-\alpha} \cos (n \pi t)\, dt=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}}{(\pi n)^{1-\alpha}}\Gamma(1-\alpha)+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\alpha}{(\pi n)^2}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n^4}\Big)\,,\,\, n\gg1$$
Integrating several times by part and using $\displaystyle \Gamma(\alpha)\alpha(1+\alpha)...(m+\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha+m+1)$ we can get a complete asymptotic series:
$$\boxed{\,\,\int_0^1 t^{-\alpha} \cos (n \pi t)\, dt\sim\frac{\sin\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}}{(\pi n)^{1-\alpha}}\Gamma(1-\alpha)+\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+2k-1)}{(\pi n)^{2k}}\,\,}$$

Comment: Thanks for the excellent solution. I will study it carefully.  I have two questions: (1) In the identity blew the graph, have you duplicated the integrand $z^{-a}$ on the left hand side? Does the third term on the right hand side appear because you are integrating the function along the positive imaginary axis? (2) What do you use to conclude the term $n^{-(1-\alpha)}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha -2}\cos (\pi x)\, d x=O(n^{-4})$?

Comment: Sorry, do not quite follow your first question. Integrating along the contour, we also integrate along the imaginary axis (what supposes substitution $z\to iz$. From the equation (0) follows (we take $i=e^\frac{\pi i}{2}$)
$$\int_0^\infty z^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi z}dz+\int_\infty^0 \big(e^\frac{\pi i}{2}z\big)^{-\alpha}e^{-\pi z}idz=0$$
The equation (1) follows in turn.

Comment: (2) - integrating by part one more time gives
$$\frac{\alpha (1+\alpha)}{\pi^2 n^{1-\alpha}}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha-2}e^{i\pi x}dx=\frac{\alpha (1+\alpha)}{\pi^2 n^{1-\alpha}}\frac{e^{i\pi z}x^{-\alpha-2}}{i\pi}\bigg|_n^\infty+\frac{\alpha (1+\alpha)(2+\alpha)}{\pi^2 n^{1-\alpha}}\frac{1}{i\pi}\int_n^\infty x^{-\alpha-3}e^{i\pi x}dx$$
We see that the term$\sim\frac{1}{n^3}$ is purely imaginary, so the real part (after the second integration by part) has the term $\sim\frac{1}{n^4}$

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. My first question is actually about the equation (0). The integrand on the left hand side has $z^{-\alpha}z^{-\alpha}$. Is it a typo?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for that. This is a typo - just correcting.

Comment: Sorry if it is too late. But is it clear that $I_R\to 0 $ as $R\to \infty$?

Comment: It's never too late :). $I_R\to0$ at $R\to\infty$ due to Jordan' lemma. We can evaluate $|I_R|$ as
$$\bigg|\int_0^{\pi/2}(Re^{i\phi})^{-\alpha}e^{i\pi Re^{i\phi}}iRe^{i\phi}d\phi\bigg|<R^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\pi R\sin\phi}d\phi$$
Using the fact that $\sin\phi\geqslant\frac{2}{\pi}$ for $\phi\in[0;\pi/2]$, for $\alpha>0$ we get
$$|I_R|<R^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-2 R\phi}d\phi=\frac{1}{2}R^{-\alpha}(1-e^{-\pi R})\to0 \,\text{at}\, R\to\infty$$

Comment: Sorry, a typo: $\sin\phi>\frac{2}{\pi}\color{red}{\phi}$

Answer (score 1):

If we go back to the definition of this specific hypergeometric function,
$$\int_0^1 t^{-\alpha} \cos (n \pi t)\, dt =\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(n \pi)^{2k} } {(2k+1-\alpha)\,(2k)! }$$

With
$$a_k=\frac{(n \pi)^{2k} } {(2k+1-\alpha)\,(2k)! }\qquad\implies \qquad \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{(n\pi)^2\,  (2 k+1-\alpha )}{2 (k+1) (2 k+1) (2 k+3-\alpha )} \sim \left(\frac {n\pi}{2k}\right)^2$$

**Edit**

If you look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.02312.pdf) (equation $3.1$) and use it, the asymptotics is immediate.

Comment: May I know why does this allow for computing the behavior of the series for large $n$? Also I notice that you drop the dependence on $\alpha$. I feel that the behavior of the integral will be different for $\alpha$ closer to $0$ or $1/2$. Is it possible to keep this dependence in the asymptotic analysis?

Comment: @John. I agree that this does not gives the behavior of the series for large $n$. What Did happen is that I was typing my non-answer (it takes me a lot of time since I am blind). Meanwhile appeared Svyatoslav's nice answer and solution and then I stopped.  I did not drop anything $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(n \pi)^{2k} } {(2k+1-\alpha)\,(2k)! }=\frac{\, _1F_2\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3-\alpha}{2};-\frac{1}{4} n^2 \pi   ^2\right)}{1-\alpha }$$

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You can use http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E2 to finish your solution.